# C++ bitwise masking and shift

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a legacy C++ binary operation code like this:

```
constexpr static uint64_t val2bin(double val) {
    uint64_t bin = (val > 0.) ? uint64_t(val/0.01)+1 : 0;
    return (bin > 510) ? 511 : bin;
}
```

And the result is then used as part of expression:

```
static uint64_t const MASK = 0x1FF;
static uint64_t const VAL_OFFSET = 10;
((val2bin(val) & MASK) << VAL_OFFSET)
```

Doesn't it put an upper limit on val we can encode in this way? I am not able to comprehend what we are trying to achieve functionally by this?

Comment: "Doesn't it put an upper limit on val we can encode in this way?" yes. "I am not able to comprehend what we are trying to achieve functionally by this?" That's between you and whatever ancient functional requirements you can scrape together about this part of code.

Comment: lol ... legacy code. I can't imagine that anybody can answer this question properly. My observation: the MASK is useless because val2bin restricts to 0x1FF anyways. The result is shifted 10 to left. I think it is not possible to say more about the code by just looking at the snipped. I assume it's determined by the usage context. Have fun with it ;)

Comment: why are you using `uint64_t(val/0.01)`? `uint64_t(val*100)` is not only **faster** but also **more correct** because 0.01 can't be represented correctly in double

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't it put an upper limit on val we can encode in this way?

It will put an upper limit on the output you can have.
The operation performed here:

```
static uint64_t const MASK = 0x1FF;
static uint64_t const VAL_OFFSET = 10;
((val2bin(val) & MASK) << VAL_OFFSET)
```

will give `val<<VAL_OFFSET` as the output for `val < 0x1FF` and hence it won't cross the limit of `uint64_t`. For values greater than `0x1FF`, the output will be `MASK << VAL_OFFSET` which still won't cross the limit of `uint64_t` (*i.e.* `MASK = 511` therefore, the output is **523264**). This is the aforementioned "upper limit" on the output *i.e.* 523264.

> I am not able to comprehend what we are trying to achieve functionally by this?

Even I am not able to exactly comprehend what functionality we are trying to achieve here. Maybe you can provide some extra piece of code around this snippet and it may help.
I know this answer states the obvious but that's all I could infer as of now.

Best.